# Htaccess Rewrite Post Method

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, post, mod-rewrite

Can we rewrite a post method based on the body parameters/values, same like query_string in get method?
ex:
Consider I have a post method where paramname=1.

```
<form action="/action.jsp">   
  <input type="text" name="paramname" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to redirect the post method only if paramname=1, if 2, i should not.

Like below for Get

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)paramname=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) example.com
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Murali Manohar M

Comment: No, that is not possible using mod_rewrite. You do not have access to the request _body_ there.